# Centos 6.7 - Unable to make the static IP

Tags: centos, networking

When I finished using "setup" to set my IP address to be static to 10.0.0.6, and restarted network service, there was a problem.

> Error: No suitable device found: no device found for connection 'System
>   eth0'.

Please refer attached file as the reference for the same.

[image: error shows in picture]

Answer (score 1):

Problem: You don't have **eth0** network interface. You have only **eth4** as `ifconfig` says.

Solution: Rewrite **eth0** to **eth4** in your network config file.

Comment: when i tried to use eth4 , the new file is created and it didn't work

Comment: @user3786256 You must edit it in file, where you set your static IP.

Comment: I tried that also but didn't work

Comment: @user3786256 Ok, so edit you answer above and append file, where you changed network setting or screenshot of it.

Comment: Please include the contents of the following files: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, `/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth*`, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` (note wildcards).

Comment: I am not aware of this and unable to understand, can you please elaborate this as i am new to linux

Comment: @user3786256 You said "When I finished using "setup" to set my IP address to be static", so how did you do it?

Comment: As the root user, `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth* /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`. What _did_ you edit when @BlueManCZ told you to edit the interface in the file?